# Take a single succeeding value out of a list of optional Parsers

Tags: haskell, parsec, option-type

I have a function that has a signature

```
tryParseAllFilesInDir :: FilePath -> [Parsec ByteString () (Maybe a)]
```

It tries to parse all files in a directory with a specific `Parser`. **It is a given that only one file will actually succeed**, but I don't know which file at runtime.

I want to take the list of optional Parsers, and take the only succeeding Parser value out. I don't know what functions I would use to achieve this.

I somehow have to go from `[Parsec ByteString () (Maybe a)] -> [Maybe a]`, and then `[Maybe a] -> Just a`.

If there is a better approach to doing this, I would appreciate those as well.

Comment: You say "specific parser", do you mean that there is only one parser which should be applied to each file? In that case why do you need a list of parsers?

Comment: @zudov yes only one specific parser is tried. But it is tried for multiple files in a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the parsers with [`runParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:runParser). This will give you a list of type `[Either ParseError (Maybe a)]`; you can use [`partitionEithers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:partitionEithers) to extract just the successful parses.

Comment: Actually, just `rights` would suffice for me. Thank you for this tip, it's actually exactly what I'm looking for, but I was thinking differently.